# Can't read the IISExpress console output, background equals foreground color

Tags: console-application, iis-express

When starting IISExpress from the command line, I can't read the (debugging) console output it generates.

See the attached screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSTwD.png).

System info:

- OS: Windows 7 Professional 64, SP1
- IIS Express version: 8.0.8418.0, 32 bit (the same problem occurs with 64bit)
- Invocation: `start "t1" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /config:appApplicationHost.config /trace:w`
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\DefaultColor` value is 0x1F
- output of `Console.BackgroundColor` and `Console.ForegroundColor`: `{ BackgroundColor = DarkBlue, ForegroundColor = White }`

What could be causing this and what needs to be done to fix it?

[image: IIS express console output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working using the following [Defaults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhsA7.png) colors.

- Screen text: 255, 255, 255
- Screen Background: 0, 0, 128
- Popup Text: 128, 0, 128
- Popup Background: 255, 255, 255

[image: Defaults]